# What pernissions are required for aws ecs wait services-stable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

On my CI I am running:
`aws ecs wait services-stable --cluster $CLUSTER --services $SERVICE`

This works perfectly with my IAM credential, but my down scoped credential for CI fails with:

`In function length(), invalid type for value: None, expected one of: ['string', 'array', 'object'], received: "null"`

The policy attached to the CI group grants the following:

`"ecs:ListClusters",
                "ecs:ListServices",
                "ecs:CreateService",
                "ecs:UpdateService",
                "ecs:DeleteService",
                "ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition",
                "ecs:DiscoverPollEndpoint",
                "ecs:Poll",
                "ecs:DeregisterTaskDefinition",
                "ecs:ListTaskDefinitions",
                "ecs:ListTasks",
                "ecs:RunTask",
                "ecs:StartTask",
                "ecs:StopTask",
                "ecs:SubmitTaskStateChange",
                "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
                "autoscaling:UpdateAutoScalingGroup",
                "iam:ListServerCertificates",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks"`

I had thought granting Poll and DiscoverPollEndpoint would cover wait. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aws ecs wait services-stable` requires `ecs:DescribeServices`.  You can see the source of the waiter [here](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/b54ceeaca5d4c1316fae0a0496422572d1f6aba5/botocore/data/ecs/2014-11-13/waiters-2.json#L42-L72).

`ecs:Poll` and `ecs:DiscoverPollEndpoint` (and a few other actions) are only used by the ECS agent; you do not need to grant those permissions to anything other than the ECS agent.

Comment: Thanks! Link to the source is also super useful for the next time.

Comment: As an after thought, it would be super helpful if the error message gave an indication of the missing permission. Maybe something to put in the backlog. aws s3 cp does that very effectively, for example, telling you which permission you have not granted.